# How to do textConnection without a temporary object

Tags: r

I'm trying to import text tables with column delimiters as '|' and line delimiters as "----------". I can get rid of the vertical bars and dashes using grep() and gsub() but I can't figure out how to avoid saving the edited lines as a temporary object. This code works:

```
foo <- gsub("|", " ",
            grep("-------", readLines(
                file("myfile", open="r")),
                 value=T, invert=T),
            fixed=T)
the.con <- textConnection(foo, "r")
agency <- read.fwf(the.con, widths=dif.widths)
```

But it fails if I try to do the whole thing in one line without saving the temporary object "foo".

```
agency <- read.fwf(textConnection( 
                   gsub("|", " ",
                        grep("-------", readLines(
                            file("myfile", open="r")),
                             value=T, invert=T),
                        fixed=T)), widths=dif.widths)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in textConnection(gsub("|", " ", grep("-------", readLines(file("myfile",  : 
  argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string
```

I'm stumped. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`textConnection` does some `deparse(substitute(...))` magic where is converts your input expression to a character vector and passes that with the calling environment to a lower level C-routine. This means you can only pass in simple expressions.

I am not going to discuss, if this is the best way to read your file, as I don't know what is in your file and that is not your question.

First, I am not sure why you want to avoid temporary objects. Even when you don't explicitly create them, R will create them when executing your code, so you won't gain anything performancewise. However, you will gain code that is difficult to read. If you want to avoid cluttering your environment with temporary variables you can put your code into a function:

```
myread <- function(filename, widths) {
  tmp <- readLines(filename)
  tmp <- grep("^[-]+$", tmp, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
  tmp <- gsub("|", " ", tmp, fixed = TRUE)
  con <- textConnection(tmp)
  on.exit(close(con))
  read.fwf(con, widths = widths)
}

agency <- myread("myfile", dif.widths)
```

Here, I also avoided the unnecessary call to `file` which creates a file connection, which in your example is not closed afterwards. When passing the filename directly to `readLines` `readLines` will open and close the connection for you.

If you really want to put everything on one line and keep it somewhat readable, I would use the `%>%` operator from `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)

agency <- readLines("myfile") %>% 
  grep("-----", ., value=TRUE, invert=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("|", " ", ., fixed=TRUE) %>% 
  textConnection %>% 
  read.fwf(, widths = dif.widths)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column delimiters are "|" then don't throw them away, use them. Get rid of the "line delimiters" using `readLines` for initial input then `read.table` with `sep ="|"`.

```
 inp <- readLines(con="file.nam")
 inp <- inp[ !grepl(grep("-------", inp) ]  # overwrite inp; drop "---------"
 dat <- read.table(text=inp, sep="|")
```

Otherwise you might be thinking about a multi-line read with `scan`.  If you want tested code you should provide an example.

Here's a method that doesn't create a temporary file in the R workspace, but rather uses `awk` to filter out the `-------` lines:

```
 inp <- read.table( pipe("awk '!/------/'  '/full_path/to/fwftest.txt'"), 
                    sep="|")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought of using "|" as separators for read.table, but the problem is that not every column is delimited; "|" is used to separate groups of columns.

Comment: As always ... the best questions will have example data suitable for testing and demonstration. That solution for using `pipe`-ed awk filtering should also work for `read.fwf`.